# how to add 2 images to one TTTableImageItem

Tags: three20

I want to add 2 images to one TTTableImageItem? but now I can just add one image and one Text like this:  [TTTableImageItem itemWithText:@"" imageURL:@"bundle://sunny.png"]

thanks

Answer (score 0):

You will need to subclass `TTTableViewItemCell` or `TTTableImageItemCell` and `TTTableImageItem` to achieve that. Look at `TTTableImageItemCell` how the image view is created and layouted.

Your `TTTableImageItem` subclass will just be a data structure class transporting the image urls, the cell subclass is the actual cell to use in the tableView.

Comment: thanks tonklon so much! I want to add 2 images ( both of which lead to a url ) side by side in one TTTableImageItem, other TTTableImageItems are common. Do you know where is the sample code?

Comment: I don't know if there is such a sample code. Look at the code of the library itself. Look at `TTTableImageItemCell` That shows you how to add one image. Should be easily extendible.

Comment: thanks tonklon so much! I searched web for days and finally Matt Vague's method in the following link should be what I need: https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/three20/WnVDQShTkZY

Comment: His tutorial is good but it was in 2009 and does not work in the latest three20 version. his TTTableDoubleImageItemCell should be the best solution for me. Perhaps because it's also based on 2009, so three places in TTTableImageItemCell.m need to be further changed according to his method. would you please help on those? thanks in advance! they are : - (void)layoutSubviews {}; - (void)didMoveToSuperview {}; - (void)setObject:(id)object {};

Comment: - (void)didMoveToSuperview {
  [super didMoveToSuperview];

  if (self.superview) {
    _imageView2.backgroundColor = self.backgroundColor;
  }
} #pragma mark -
#pragma mark TTTableViewCell


///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
- (void)setObject:(id)object {
  if (_item != object) {
    [super setObject:object];

    TTTableImageItem* item = object;
    _imageView2.style = item.imageStyle;
    _imageView2.defaultImage = item.defaultImage;
    _imageView2.urlPath = item.imageURL;}
}

Comment: self.textLabel.font = [[self class] fontForImageIt;if ([_item isKindOfClass:[TTTableRightImageItem class]]) {self.textLabel.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;         self.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;} else {self.textLabel.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentLeft;}}

Comment: so sorry, the above code may be in a format hard to read. the third, - (void)layoutSubviews {} is too long and I can't copy here. It's also in TTTableImageItemCell.m  hope get your help. thanks!